# Passing output of multiline instance ids to another input (EC2 boto3)

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I have the following python3 code. The purpose is to terminate all stopped instances that pass the given filters.
I am able to make the code work, just that I am finding it difficult to pass the list (multiline) of instance ids onto another variable - Long story short, I am not able to convert the multiline output of strings into a single line string with each output in single quotes separated by commas. I will provide the example output desired right below my code:

```
import jmespath
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

from pathlib import Path
import re
import configparser

homepath = str(Path.home())

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read(homepath + '/Documents/Projects/in-team/scripts/python/config')
result = []


class StackName:
    pass


for section_name in config.sections():
    # Removes the word "profile" from the profile name, if present
    if re.search('^profile', section_name):
        section_name = re.split(' ', section_name, maxsplit=1)[1]


    session = boto3.session.Session(
        profile_name=section_name,
        region_name='us-west-2'
        )
    # Create EC2 client
    ec2client = session.resource('ec2')

    try:
        instances = ec2client.instances.filter(
            Filters=[
                {
                    'Name': 'instance-state-name',
                    'Values': ['stopped']
                },
                # {
                #     'Name': 'tag:Name',
                #     'Values': ['migrated*']
                # },
                {
                    'Name': 'tag:Environment',
                    'Values': ['Dev']
                }
            ]
        )
        for instance in instances:
            # print(instance.id.split())
            print([instance.id)
        # ids = ['i-089d6e80fa3f59129']
        # for id in ids:
        #     ec2client.Instance(id).modify_attribute(
        #         DisableApiTermination={
        #             'Value': False
        #         }
        #     )
        # ec2client.Instance(id).terminate()

                
    except ClientError as e:
        if (e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'ValidationError' and
                e.response['Error']['Message'] == "No updates are to be performed."):
            print("%s: No updates are to be performed." % StackName)
        else:
            print("Unexpected error: %s" % e)
```

Output of the print command is as follows:

```
i-06c517d7378ef7070
i-0155f6f9dbfe7b76e
i-08c5d054b6dbde86f
```

If we see the commented out line

```
ids = ['i-089d6e80fa3f59129']
```

I want the output to be passed on as:

```
ids = ['i-06c517d7378ef7070','i-0155f6f9dbfe7b76e','i-08c5d054b6dbde86f']
```

How is this possible?
I tried multiple ways like join, split, etc but it ends up adding delimiter within each string.

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my overall problem finally. Here is the updated code:

```
import jmespath
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

from pathlib import Path
import re
import configparser

homepath = str(Path.home())

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read(homepath + '/Documents/Projects/in-team/scripts/python/config')
result = []


class StackName:
    pass


for section_name in config.sections():
    # Removes the word "profile" from the profile name, if present
    if re.search('^profile', section_name):
        section_name = re.split(' ', section_name, maxsplit=1)[1]


    session = boto3.session.Session(
        profile_name=section_name,
        region_name='us-west-2'
        )
    # Create EC2 client
    ec2client = session.resource('ec2')

    try:
        instances = ec2client.instances.filter(
            Filters=[
                {
                    'Name': 'instance-state-name',
                    'Values': ['stopped']
                },
                {
                    'Name': 'tag:Name',
                    'Values': ['decommissioned*']
                },
                {
                    'Name': 'tag:Environment',
                    'Values': ['Dev']
                }
            ]
        )
        instance_ids = [instance.id for instance in instances]
        print(instance_ids)
        for id in instance_ids:
            ec2client.Instance(id).modify_attribute(
                DisableApiTermination={
                    'Value': False
                }
            )
            ec2client.Instance(id).terminate()

                
    except ClientError as e:
        if (e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'ValidationError' and
                e.response['Error']['Message'] == "No updates are to be performed."):
            print("%s: No updates are to be performed." % StackName)
        else:
            print("Unexpected error: %s" % e)
```